# Bluetooth leaked IntentReceiver. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Tags: android, bluetooth, receiver

I was following a tutorial and trying to build a small android bluetooth app. I followed the exact steps but encountered an error while trying to run the app. The code has been attached below. Please help me to fix this unregistered receiver issue.

```
package com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    Button connectNew;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
    ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
    IntentFilter filter;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        init();
        if(btAdapter==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Adapter Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
                turnOnBT();
            }
            getPairedDevices();
            startDiscovery();
        }
    }

    private void startDiscovery() {
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private void turnOnBT() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    private void getPairedDevices() {
        devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(devicesArray.size()>0){
            for(BluetoothDevice device: devicesArray){
                pairedDevices.add(device.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, 0);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        connectNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConnectNew);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        btAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    listAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                    String s = "";
                    for(int j=0; j<pairedDevices.size(); j++){
                        if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(j))){
                            s = "(Paired)";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" \n"+device.getAddress());
                }
                else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                    // Add code
                }
                else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){

                }
                else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                    if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                        turnOnBT();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED );
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(listAdapter.getItem(position).contains("(Paired)")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is paired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is not paired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have attached the logs as well.

```
02/18 23:59:21: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp/com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 17545 on device sony-c6603-BX903JZAQZ
W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp, real application class is null.
W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex) with checksum 0x6beeb489 in OatFile /data/data/com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp/cache/slice-slice_4-classes.dex
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
E/ActivityThread: Activity com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp.MainActivity$2@37f3f328 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                  android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp.MainActivity$2@37f3f328 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:909)
                      at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:710)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1664)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1644)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1638)
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:489)
                      at com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:125)
                      at com.example.sparky.bluetoothtestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 42.694ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

```
@Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try{
             if(receiver!=null)
                 unregisterReceiver(receiver);
         }catch(Exception e)
         {
         }
         super.onDestroy();    
     }
```

Hope this helps.